# Cheapest method to setup HTTPS?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I've setup my ssl cert in AWS through EC2 using the Elastic IP Address and Elastic Load Balancing. It costs me about 20$ per month to run this.

Does anyone have cheaper suggestions?

Comment: Your doing something else to rack up the $20 because the certs from the certificate manager don't cost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are using your EC2 instance for...   If for a web service, look at API Gateway in front of a Lambda function for a serverless architecture.  If for a website and it is static, consider hosting in a S3 bucket.

Comment: It's non static, similar functionality to a blog/forum

Comment: 1. Make sure you are using AWS Certificate Manager for your SSL cert instead of buying/importing your own.
2. You don't need an Elastic IP when using an ALB/ELB.  Just create a Route 53 A record to your ALB/ELB (alias).
3. You a T2 Linux EC2 instance with T2 Unlimited checked.
4. If you don't need your site 24/7, then control the lifetime of your EC2 instance with an Autoscaler and use the AutoScaler's scheduler i.e shut down the instance(s) at night/weekends using the CRON expression.

Comment: Yes, using  the certificate manager. Using my site 24/7 so want to keep the instance up all the time.

This is my current setup: https://ibb.co/gyggiH. So I can remove the elastic IP? Although elastic IP is free, so doesn't matter

Comment: Correct, if you are routing traffic thru your ALB to support SSL termination, then ALB already has a public URL, so just create a Route 53 A record to give it a friendly name.  And the EIP does not incur a charge if being used, but it is not required either in this scenario.

Might want to consider if you can make your site a single page application using something like Angular.  With S3 hosting, all your ALB, EC2, cert manager, all go away, giving you a virtually free hosting platform.

Comment: Cool, so that can completely eliminate my T2 linux instance? (ie just access files through S3)?

Comment: Yes, you can configure an S3 bucket to host a static website, which includes single page applications.  We do it with Angular apps talking to web services.

Answer (score 0):

Let'sencrypt would be the ideal solution for your case. https://letsencrypt.org/ offers free ssl certificates that you can generate and import into your ACM and attach them from ELB
OR
If you prefer it directly to your EC2 instance then you can install them in your apache (httpd) web server.
Refer: https://www.godaddy.com/help/apache-install-a-certificate-centos-5238
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_a4wRsT6LaI

Answer (score 0):

Use certificates from the AWS certificate manager and you won't pay anything. They are free. https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CloudFront as the gateway to your application which can use AWS Certificate Manager issued SSL certificates for free. There are no upfront commitments and you will pay only for the usage (More details refer [CloudFront Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/)). You can connect your EC2 instance to CloudFront to receive traffic.

This will provide you a higher performance by caching the static content while reducing the load for your backend further reducing costs at scale.